# Serial interface RS232 control

Tags: interface, hardware

I am using Mathematica 10.3 and Windows 10 Pro 64-Bit.

I would like to test a stepper motor by simply sending strings over the serial interface.

Is the code below the right way to open the serial interface, adjust the baud rate etc., send a string, and close the interface.
In my case I have only `COM3`, and the setting parameters required for the motor are given below.

```
dev = DeviceOpen[
  "Serial", {"COM3", "BaudRate" -> 9600, "DataBits" -> 8, 
   "Parity" -> None, "StopBits" -> 1}]

DeviceWrite[dev, "SEND STRING"];

DeviceClose[dev];
```

`DeviceConfigure` does not work for the serial interface (`DeviceConfigure::noop: "DeviceConfigure not supported for "Serial".`)

Comment: Well, it would seem to me that the most expedient way to check whether your code works would be to simply *try it out*. What happens when you try to execute it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have successfully tested your code, it does work.

```
piratebus = 
  DeviceOpen[
   "Serial", {"COM8", "BaudRate" -> 115200, "DataBits" -> 8, 
    "Parity" -> None, "StopBits" -> 1}];
```

Leave some time before this

```
DeviceWrite[piratebus, "?\n"];

FromCharacterCode@DeviceReadBuffer[piratebus]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]