# Unable to write to MM3000, stepper motor

Tags: serial

[Serial interface RS232 control](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98792/serial-interface-rs232-control)

I am using a stepper motor connected with RS232 protocol. But I am unable to write or read. I don't get any errors and I have waited after I open the device and then Write and read. 
I am also using Windows 10 with Mathematica 10.3

This is the code I am using:

```
MM3000 = DeviceOpen[
  "Serial", {"COM5", "BaudRate" -> 9600, "DataBits" -> 8, 
   "Parity" -> None, "StopBits" -> 1}]
```

wait and then:

```
DeviceWrite[MM3000, "2PA+3000"]
FromCharacterCode@DeviceReadBuffer[MM3000]
```

A few minutes ago I had something read but then it just stop working. I have been waiting for an hour trying to figure out what just happened but I have no idea what the problem can be.

Comment: Can you reproduce the `DeviceWrite[MM3000, "?\n"]; FromCharacterCode@DeviceReadBuffer[MM3000]` results that rhermans suggested in [his answer to the linked question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98799/27951)?

Comment: Also, if your "stepper motor" is actually a Newport MM3000 motion controller, as the name might imply, the [manual for that device](http://www.newport.com/images/webdocuments-en/images/12590.pdf) says that "An MM3000 command (or a sequence of commands) has to be terminated with a carriage return character" (page 3.10). Have you tried perhaps "2PA+3000\n" as your command?